# jQuery Simple Combobox not rendered correctly after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I'm using the jquery simple combobox plugin (https://github.com/ivkremer/jquery-simple-combobox). I have two comboboxes on my page. If an option is selected from the first combobox, the second should reflect this with some new values. That works. But what happens is, that the replaced combobox is now rendered as a standard combobox and not in the style and functionality of the "simple combobox" plugin. So I tried the following code (which attaches a change listener to the first combobox):

```
    $('#productlineSelektor').scombobox('change', function(){
        $.ajax({
                url : myURL,
                cache : false,
                type : 'POST',
                data : $(myForm).serialize(),
                success : function(result) {
                  $('#selectBoxDiv').html(result);
                  $('#selectBox').scombobox({...options...});
                }
            });
     });
```

'selectBoxDiv' is the div containing the combobox, 'selectBox' is the id of the combobox itself. The returned result contains the combobox.

But the "$('#selectBox').scombobox({...options...});" does not seem to work (it should re-initialize the inserted combobox to match the functionality and style of the simple combobox plugin). If I execute this line after the change listener has finished, it works. (I just implemented a button on the page which I click after the change listener has finished)

Could it be that the DOM tree is only updated after the eventlistener has finished?

Kind regards,
Falk